# Error Running Catkin_Make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing/uninstalling some packages from source using rosinstall, I can no longer run `catkin_make` without error.  I've tried removing the packages I installed, removing/reinstalling the catkin package, running `wstool update`, and other things.

The error message makes reference to `catkin_EXTRAS_DIR`, but I can't seem to find any information on what this is.

Can anyone help me understand what I can do to fix this?  What is catkin_EXTRAS_DIR?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build"
####
-- +++ catkin
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build;/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/cmake
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:3 (message):


  Assertion failed: catkin_EXTRAS_DIR (value is '')

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:34 (assert)
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:9532: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Thanks,
Justin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240767/error-running-catkin_make/) by [jwasserstein](https://answers.ros.org/users/27646/jwasserstein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-31**:
Please post your error message as text and format it with the "preformatted text" (010101) button so that it is searchable and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not entirely clear exactly what you've done to get here, but it's clear that your workspace is kind of messed up.

`catkin_EXTRAS_DIR` is one of the variables used internally by catkin during the build process; if it's not set it means that some file for catkin is corrupt or empty.

The first steps at troubleshooting would be to remove the build and devel directories in your workspace, and since the CMakeLists.txt link at the root of your workspace seems messed up, you should remove that too. A fresh build will re-create all of these.

After that, next steps will depend on how you installed ROS. If you did a binary install, you should reinstall any apt packages you suspect are damaged with `apt-get install --reinstall <package>`. If you did a source install, you should make sure that the source files are still intact, and then run the build steps (catkin_make_isolated, etc) again.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwasserstein](https://answers.ros.org/users/27646/jwasserstein/) on 2016-08-01**:
I tried removing build, devel, and CMakeLists.txt, then building again, but this didn't work.  I ended up re-installing ROS which fixed the issue.  I also had some boot issues which I attributed to a corrupt SD card, so that might be what caused this.  Thanks for your help.